# Accessing lazily eager loaded properties

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following query returning an object which is then sent to the view

```
$user = $this->user->find($id)
            ->load(
                'images',
                'albums',
                'measurements',
                'medicalAnswers.medicalQuestion',
                'goals.strengthGoalDesc.excersise',
                'goals.distanceGoalDesc.excersise',
                'goals.bodyGoalDesc',
                'client.trainers.user',
                'trainer.clients.user',
                'trainer.classes',
                'trainer.types',
                'trainer.programs.weeks.days.sessions.phases.excersises',
                'trainer.testimonials'
            );
```

In the view I am doing a number of things to display all this information and it was all going great until I tried to access the properties related to these relationships

```
            'goals.strengthGoalDesc.excersise',
            'goals.distanceGoalDesc.excersise',
```

here is an example of what is being returned for a goal with a strength goal desc that has an excersise

```
{
"id":"2",
"userId":"1",
"title":"strength goal title",
"goalDesc":"This should describe my strngth goal in text form",
"goalStatus":"0",
"bodyGoalId":null,
"strengthGoalId":"1",
"distanceGoalId":null,
"created_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16",
"updated_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16",
"strength_goal_desc":{
    "id":"1",
    "excersise":{
        "id":"1",
        "name":"Leg Extension",
        "type":"Resistance",
        "variation":null, 
        "equipment":"Machine", 
        "focus":"Legs", 
        "desc":"", 
        "video":null, 
        "created_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:18", 
        "updated_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:18"},
    "sets":"4", 
    "reps":"10",
    "weight":"70.00", 
    "created_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16", 
    "updated_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16"}, 
"distance_goal_desc":null,
"body_goal_desc":null}
```

my first question is why are bodyGoalDesc, distanceGoalDesc and strengthGoalDesc being converted to snake case?  Nowhere in what I have done(the database, raltionship methods etc) have I used snake case.

Now my main problem

I can access the goal with

```
@foreach($user->goals as $goal)
    {{ $goal }}
@endforeach
```

and $goal->strengthGoalDesc returns

```
{"id":"1","excersise":{"id":"1","name":"Leg Extension","type":"Resistance","variation":null,"equipment":"Machine","focus":"Legs","desc":"","video":null,"created_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:18","updated_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:18"},"sets":"4","reps":"10","weight":"70.00","created_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16","updated_at":"2014-01-16 15:51:16"}
```

but $goal->strengthGoalDesc->excersise just returns 1 and $goal->strengthGoalDesc->excerises->name gives

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/app/views/users/show.blade.php)
```

and trying to access it like an array $goal->strengthGoalDesc['excersises'] just returns 1

edit: code where I am trying to access the name property

```
@elseif($goal->strengthGoalId !== null)
   <th>{{ 'Strength' }}</th>
   <th>

      Excersise: {{ $goal->strengthGoalDesc->excersise->name) }}
      Weight: {{ $goal->strengthGoalDesc->weight }}</br>
      Sets: {{ $goal->strengthGoalDesc->sets }}</br>
      Reps: {{ $goal->strengthGoalDesc->reps }}</br>
   </th>
```

and I thought it might be because it is a collection but wrapping it in a foreach only returned an invalid argument exception as it says it is not an object

I am sure I am jsut doing something stupid but this has me totally lost

var_dump($goal->strengthGoalDesc) ouputs

```
null
object(StrengthGoalDesc)[506]
  protected 'guarded' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'table' => string 'strengthGoalDescs' (length=17)
  protected 'connection' => null
  protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
  protected 'perPage' => int 15
  public 'incrementing' => boolean true
  public 'timestamps' => boolean true
  protected 'attributes' => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'excersise' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sets' => string '4' (length=1)
      'reps' => string '10' (length=2)
      'weight' => string '70.00' (length=5)
      'created_at' => string '2014-01-16 15:51:16' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-01-16 15:51:16' (length=19)
  protected 'original' => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'excersise' => string '1' (length=1)
      'sets' => string '4' (length=1)
      'reps' => string '10' (length=2)
      'weight' => string '70.00' (length=5)
      'created_at' => string '2014-01-16 15:51:16' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2014-01-16 15:51:16' (length=19)
  protected 'relations' => 
    array (size=1)
      'excersise' => 
        object(Excersise)[480]
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'table' => string 'excersises' (length=10)
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=10)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'exists' => boolean true
          protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
  protected 'hidden' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'visible' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'appends' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'fillable' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'dates' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'touches' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'observables' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'with' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'exists' => boolean true
  protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
null
```

and *var_dump($goal->stengthGoalDesc['excersise']*

```
null
string '1' (length=1)
null
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump` to see what type of object it is. It may be an array, and not an Std object. Try `$goal->strengthGoalDesc['excersise']`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply $goal->strengthGoalDesc['excersise'] simply returns '1' and I have added the output from var_dump to my question it looks like an object to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this a structure problem (all the data looks good but you call it in a bad moment)

```
@foreach($user->goals as $goal)
    {{ $goal }}
    $goal->strengthGoalDesc->excersise 
    //this will throw an error because not all Goals have strengthGoalDesc
@endforeach
```

Please look in your foreach's or paste some more code. (where you try to use strengthGoalDesc)

Answer (score 2):

Notice the `null` outputs which the `var_dump()` gives. The first and the third time when you try to access `$goal->stengthGoalDesc->excersise`. The `$goal->stengthGoalDesc` variable is `null`, which results in an **ErrorException**.

Try wrapping it in an **if statement** to check if `$goal->strengthGoalDesc` is not null:

```
if( $goal->strengthGoalDesc !== null ) {
    var_dump( $goal->strengthGoalDesc->exercise );
}
```

That should resolve the ErrorException. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My particular problem here is that it should not be null because there is information in the database for that particular relationship.  information the is returned by $goal->strengthGoalDesc (see 5th code block down for output) but that I can't access individually for some reason

Comment: @Ir1sh I see. So the problems seems to lie in the relationship binding between the models, correct?

Try dumping the raw queries with `DB::getQueryLog()`. Maybe you will find the answer there - as an ORM does not always work as expected.

Comment: Sorry I should add that it is wrapped in an if statement

Comment: Did the raw queries get you any further? Try running them against the database yourself, most of the times this helps you better understand what's happening under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have overlapping attribute and relationship names. You have a database column named `exercise` as well as a relation named the same, and attributes take precedence over relations. Rename the column to `exerciseId` or something.

As for the convertion to snake_case, try setting `public static $snakeAttributes = false` on your model(s) or a base model which all your models extend from.